# Método Replace no VBA substitui texto indevidamente em todas as planilhas da pasta de trabalho

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, replace

Há um problema com o método "Replace" do objeto "Range". Quando anteriormente executado o comando "Localizar" (e substituir ou não) na interface de usuário, com a opção "Pasta de trabalho" selecionada, o método "Replace" ignora a delimitação do intervalo de células com o qual o método foi chamado e SUBSTITUI TODAS AS OCORRÊNCIAS do texto procurado EM TODAS AS PLANILHAS da pasta de trabalho. O problema é que até onde pesquisei não há parâmetro para alterar essa opção de "Pasta de trabalho" para "Planilha" no VBA (nem no método "Find" nem no método "Replace"). É até mesmo impossível saber o que está selecionado para esse parâmetro.

Como, no meu caso, não posso fazer a substituição do texto que desejo em outras planilhas, além de uma específica, fica inviabilizada a utilização do método "Search". Há a solução de usar o método "Find" e, após testar se a célula é ainda pertencente à planilha desejada, alterar o valor da célula encontrada com um comando, e depois usar o método "FindNext", e assim por diante. Mas a planilha pode ter milhares de linhas e muitas ocorrências do texto pesquisado e essa solução impacta muito a performance.

Se alguém se deparou com esse problema e tem alguma ideia fico grato.

Summary: There is a problem with the method "Replace" in the object "Range". When previously executed the command "Find" (and replace or not) in the user-interface, with the option "Workbook"  ("Pasta de trabalho", in portuguese) selected, the method "Replace" ignores the delimitation of the range over wich the method was called and REPLACES ALL THE OCCURENCIES of the searched text IN ALL WORKSHEETS...

Answer (score -4):

Estamos falando de um bug do Excel na versão 365 atualizada (não verifiquei se já ocorria em outras versões). Ele foi reportado à Microsoft. Até que seja corrigido há as seguintes soluções de contorno possíveis:

**1) FUNÇÃO REPLACE**

Usar os métodos 'Find' e 'FindNext' combinados com a FUNÇÃO 'Replace' (não o método do objeto intervalo), mediante verificação da propriedade 'Worksheet' de cada célula encontrada, como descrito na pergunta.

A pesquisa deve ser iniciada na primeira célula da planilha desejada, de modo que ao ser encontrada célula fora da planilha a iteração deve ser interrompida. Não adotei essa solução devido ao custo, porque no meu caso se esperam centenas de milhares ou mais substituições.

**2) PROMPT DE CONFIRMAÇÃO**

Exibir um prompt para confirmação pelo usuário do prosseguimento da execução, alertando para a necessidade de não estar selecionado 'pasta de trabalho' na caixa de diálogo da ferramenta 'Localizar e substituir' do Excel, ou serão feitas alterações em toda a pasta de trabalho que irão inutizá-la. Foi o que adotei como solução imediata.

**3) PROTEGER E DESPROTEGER DEMAIS PLANILHAS**

Proteger todas as outras planilhas, em que a substituição seja indesejada, antes de se aplicar o método 'Replace', e tornar a desproteger as planilhas. Se necessário, deve ser salva a lista de planilhas que já estejam protegidas, para que não fiquem desprotegidas indevidamente depois da execução do script.

Haverá ainda um problema: se a aplicação fizer uso de planilhas protegidas com células desbloqueadas. Será trabalhoso, se forem muitos intervalos, bloqueá-los, antes do 'Replace', para depois desbloqueá-los.

Não foi o meu caso, então foi essa a solução que adotei por fim.